# I have to click 2 times to the link in mobile view of my Next JS application in order to change routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-router

I am building a Next JS application,

On the desktop view, there is no problem, but when it changes to the mobile view after a scroll event or changing routes when I want to click on a link/button, etc. I need to click two times on it. I am suspicious that after an event, the focus on the page is being lost, but there is no overflow or something. I couldn't figure out where the focus was gone.

Here is an example of my code

```
 <Link href={storyUrl}>
        <a className="group inline-flex flex-col mb-4 md:mb-11 space-y-2 ">
          <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
            {isDeleted && (
              <div className="group">
                <Info className="text-slate-400" />
                <div className="hidden rounded-lg p-2 text-xs bg-gray-100 absolute z-50 group-hover:block shadow-md w-48 mt-5">
                  This story has been deleted or in draft
                </div>
              </div>
            )}

            {draft && (
              <span className="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-0.5 rounded-full text-sm font-medium bg-purple-50 text-purple-800">
                Draft
              </span>
            )}
            <h2
              className={`text-slate-900 text-3xl font-semibold leading-9 tracking-md transition ease-in-out duration-150 group-hover:text-purple-700 ${
                isDeleted ? 'line-through' : ''
              }`}
            >
              {title}
            </h2>
          </div>
          <p className="text-slate-500 text-sm tracking-sm line-clamp-2 break-words w-full xl:w-[600px]  ">
            {infoText}
          </p>
        </a>
      </Link>
```

Thanks for any responses in advance

I tried to change the Links to the router.push but as I thought it was irrelevant.

Comment: you have to add some fragments of your code, we can not help you this way.
 btw,  if you are navigating through your components, instead of using router.push, use native Links

Comment: I did add some.